# How can I highlight only certain areas of an image?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I've got an image of a human skeleton with approx 60 areas I want to highlight and make clickable. Those are in a circle and numbered from 1-60.

The whole idea is I want to click on the nubmers (on the image) and highlight that part of the image.

I've used JQuery to hover over the numbers/area and highlight (hover over with mouse) and when the user clicks on the number I'm getting the clicked number and processing on the server side code. (.NET C#)

But I want the place where I click should remain the colour... Hovering over the number and changing the colour works fine... But I want when it's click the colour should change on the image / persisted...

Below are the samples which changes the colour when you hover over with your mouse, but when you click the colour is not changing.

http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/

http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/demo_simple.html

any ideas how to highlight the some areas on the image?

**sample code below:**

```
 <img class="map" src="Images/Figure_Human_Image1.png" alt="" usemap="#Skeleton17"  / >
 <map name="Skeleton17" >
 <area title="1" alt="1" href="#" shape="circle" coords="13,174,7" / >
 <area title="2" alt="2" href="#" shape="circle" coords="27,159,7" / >
```

[image: How to PERMANENT highlight on the image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers about swapping out images will work. That said, by doing this in images, you end up using more bandwidth than you really need to use for this. One of two things will happen: either people will download a bunch of images that they never load, or they will have to wait to download the new image each time they click. For users with a high speed connection, that's not going to be an issue, but there is definitely room for users on slow connections (or perhaps mobile devices) to experience this as a negative.

Better would be to only have one version of the image, which is what it looks like on the first load. The trick is to make the numbers on the image transparent. Then you can just have the user's browser change the background color when they click. And as a bonus, if you ever want to add other colors to indicate other things, that's simple too! And you can have any combination of numbers highlighted.

After some experimentation, I found that the `style` attribute on the `<area>` can't be used to set background colors, so you would need something else to enforce the colors. I suggest a `<div>` positioned in the same place as each circle via something like:
`<div id='div1' style='position:relative; top:-400px; left:5px; height:30px; width:30px; z-index:-1'>&nbsp;</div>` where you would adjust the top/left values to place it where you need it. The `z-index:-1` is important to make it show up behind the image. To experiment with the placing of these divs, you may want to go ahead and set the background-color to something so that you can see them.

Once you have a transparent image and have all of the divs placed, you'd just need a bit of jQuery to activate it. Something like this:

```
$('area').click(function(){
    var number = $(this).attr('title');
    $('#div'+number).css('background-color', 'red');
})
```

Comment: thanks for the info... just need a bit step more. I made number 1 on the image transparant and I also created a transparant circle.png file (just a red circle). I tested: I was able to set the div on the number one (1). btw: I change relative to absolute and remove the z-indez.otherwise with z-index I wasn't able to see the image. I used background-image, But why don't I get this circle.png on the number 1?  <div id='div1' style='position: absolute; top: 265px; left: 31px; height: 40px; width: 40px;'/> - <Yourcode + > $('#div' + number).css(' background-image', 'url(/Images/cicrle.png)');

Comment: There might be an issue with displaying multiple layers of images. Usually it can be handled, but I think it would be much easier to sort out by just setting the background-color of the div, as I showed in my code. It also removes one download from the amount of stuff that the client has to retrieve (al beit a tiny download). Is there a reason you don't want to use the background-color attribute of the div?

Comment: Everything works fine as you described.. but when I use background-color then the numbers are nog shown... I get yellow/red box on the numbers.

Comment: That's why you need the z-index to put the colored box under the transparent image.

Comment: when I add z-index:-1  I don't get the colour, when I remove I get the colour on the number. what am I doing wrong?    <div id='div1' style='position: absolute; top: 265px; left: 31px; height: 10px; width: 10px; z-index:-1'/>

Comment: It's possible that your browser is caching the non-transparent version of the image. Try setting the page's background color to something non-white to ensure that the numbers are indeed showing up as transparent. If they are not, then you'll need to clear your cache (or name the image differently).

Comment: Or make sure you are actually using a transparent png in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

As Greg B suggested, you could create the skeletons images just changing the highlighted number such as:

```
Images/Figure_Human_Image1.png    : this is your original image with no highlight
Images/Figure_Human_Image1_h1.png : this is the skeleton image with number 1 highlighted
Images/Figure_Human_Image1_h2.png : this is the skeleton image with number 2 highlighted
and so on...
```

Then you use jquery to switch the source of the image with the correct image highlighted been replaced. If the user clicked on number 1 than you replace the src with the image 'Images/Figure_Human_Image1_h1.png'

You can do that by adding a click event in `area` through jquery. In your case the title attribute of the tag area correspond to the number clicked so it would be something like this:

```
$('area').click(function(){
    var number = $(this).attr('title');
    $('img').attr('src','Images/Figure_Human_Image1_h'+number+'.png');
})
```

Comment: Ok I wil l create 32 images (not 60, my misspelling). Every image is a number and when someoneclicks on a number I need to put overlay this image?  But how to put e.g. number 8 highlted image on the number 8 general image.... ? What's the code, keyword so I can google?

Comment: You don need to put overlay the image, you have to replace the old image with new highlighted one. You can do that by binding a click event in the area and then replacing the img.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need any server side code.

You could create the 60 images of the various highlighted skeletons and then using JavaScript,  switch the source of the image with the one with the correct highlight

Comment: do you mean <img> but how to put on the numbers? Could you please clarify? please detail it:(